# how to check that a particular date already exists in database or not

Tags: php, mysql

There is a table which has datetime of employees log in and log out. I have to set their status login or log out, according to this datetime. I have to apply the condition on date time, that if date exists in database first time then it will be login and same date exists second time for same employee then it will be log out.

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "if date exists in database first time then it will be login and same date exists second time for same employee then it will be log out"?

Comment: it means in the database table there will be two entries for the employee having all the same field values except date.so i have to check on the basis of date that entry is first time or second time.

Comment: i m trying to apply condition if date exists.but its not going to work out.

Answer (score 0):

If i get you right, the next code can help you. (this is the main idea of how doing it)
I'm assuming that the table is like:

+workers_logs

- id
- worker_id
- actiontime
- bla

and we will have an array named workers which its structre will be:

```
workers[ worker_id ] [0] = 'login'
workers[ worker_id ] [1] = 'logout'
workers[ worker_id ] [2] = 'login'
workers[ worker_id2 ] [0] = 'login'
workers[ worker_id2 ] [1] = 'logout'
workers[ worker_id2 ] [2] = 'login'
```

//the code:

```
$workers = array();
$getWorkersLogs = mysql_query("SELECT worker_id,actiontime FROM workers_logs ORDER BY id ASC"); //Notice for: ORDER BY id ASC - it's very imporatnt in your case.
while($logs = mysql_fetch_array($getWorkersLogs))
{
 if((!array_key_exists($logs['worker_id'] , $workers)) || count($workers[$log['worker_id']]) % 2 == 0 )
 {
   //This is the first time we are dealing with this worker (so it's login)
   //or it's an even number.
       .....
       .....

   //Add this worker id to our array so next time will be logout
     $workers[$logs['worker_id']][] = 'login'
 }
 else
 {
     $workers[$logs['worker_id']][] = 'logout'

 }
}
```